# passing RGB value to CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor is not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

for Orange i pass rgb value 255-140-0

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);  For me its drawing yellow! not orange.

I try to test some random value below 255 to the CGContextSetRGBStokeColor, it drawing white color to me.  I dont know why it like that!

@ALL can any one advice me in this issue

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html), it states that the values passed for Red Green and Blue are floats

```
The graphics context for which to set the current stroke color.
red
The red intensity value for the color to set. The DeviceRGB color space permits the specification of a value ranging from 0.0 (zero intensity) to 1.0 (full intensity).
green
The green intensity value for the color to set. The DeviceRGB color space permits the specification of a value ranging from 0.0 (zero intensity) to 1.0 (full intensity).
blue
The blue intensity value for the color to set. The DeviceRGB color space permits the specification of a value ranging from 0.0 (zero intensity) to 1.0 (full intensity).
alpha
A value that specifies the opacity level. Values can range from 0.0 (transparent) to 1.0 (opaque). Values outside this range are clipped to 0.0 or 1.0.
```

So the values have to be between 0.0 and 1.0. You are putting too large numbers in. In future, please check the documentation first.

Comment: Nick Bull  Thanks man!  I divided those value with 255 its working for me thanks a lot!